# JBoss AS 7.1.1 deploying error

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jboss7.x

I have an error during deploy and I did not understand what that mean. Here is the log:

```
16:54:50,298 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/content/RQ.war/WEB-INF/lib/mail-1.4.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:54:52,888 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 6379ms - Started 632 of 876 services (163 services failed or missing dependencies, 76 services are passive or on-demand)
```

In that log I can see only ONE ERROR and ONE WARN. And application does not deploys..

Comment: can you post the complete server startup log ? if it aint too large?

Comment: It is too large) but there is no any useful info. By the way I have solved this problem. An oracle driver was not installed correctly. I re-installed it and it works fine now.

Comment: Great, please answer your own question in that case

Comment: It seems, both question and answer currently provide too few details to be useful for anybody else.

Answer (score 0):

An oracle driver was not installed correctly. I re-installed it and it works fine now.